# Remove lines matching regex in a yaml file with Go

Tags: regex, go

I have the following yaml `myfile.yml` file :

```
variables:
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  Grpc__Client__Service__Target: ${URL}.${PREFIX}.mydomain.com:443

include:
  - project: "myproject"
    file: "/test.yml"

stages:
  - mystage
```

where I would like to remove the line beginning with "  Grpc"

my code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    filename := "myfile.yml"

    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    check(errReadFile)

    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    m := regexp.MustCompile("^  Grpc__(.*)$") 
    grpcRemoved := m.ReplaceAllString(string(content), "")
    fmt.Println(grpcRemoved)
}
```

At the end, nothing is removed.

I tested my regex using `MatchString`, it returned `true` for :

```
matchString, _ := regexp.MatchString("^  Grpc__(.*)$", "  Grpc__Client__Service__Target: ${URL}.${PREFIX}.mydomain.com:443")
```

but

```
matchStringFile, _ := regexp.MatchString("^  Grpc__(.*)$", string(content))
```

returned `false`, which is not I expect. Then I suppose `ReplaceAllString` is not working because it doesn't find anything to replace.

What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your regex: `"^  Grpc__(.*)$"`, `^` means start of the string and `$` means end of the string.

This string: `"  Grpc__Client__Service__Target: ${URL}.${PREFIX}.mydomain.com:443"` matchs because it starts with `Grpc__` and ends with `mydomain.com:443`

But the string in yaml file starts with `variables: ...` and ends with `... -mystage` so it doen't match.

Try using `"Grpc__(.*)"` (no `^` and `$`) and it will works.

Comment: Or, enable multiline mode: see https://github.com/google/re2/blob/7bab3dc83df6a838cc004cc7a7f51d5fe1a427d5/doc/syntax.txt#L65,L68